# Populating column using a for loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am attempting to populate A2:A13 with the months of the year. Obviously I could just type the months but I'm populating them using strings derived from 12 workbooks in a folder. I'm doing this because I'm also going to be populating other columns with other data so the same method will apply and I think it's a useful exercise.

The code is set to loop through all the workbooks in the containing folder, I want it to populate A2:A13 with the string derived from each workbook using a for loop as below. At the moment however each cell is just populated with December.

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub CompileRandomCheckingData()
    Dim MyPath As String, strfilename As String, mnth As String
    Dim EOYR As Workbook, indv As Workbook
    Dim psdsht As Worksheet, eoyrsht As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'--> Set Containing Folder
MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\alistairw\Desktop\temppsdreports2011"
strfilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

    '--> If folder is empty then exit
    If Len(strfilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until strfilename = ""

    '--> Define each workbook
    Set EOYR = ThisWorkbook
    Set eoyrsht = EOYR.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set indv = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\alistairw\Desktop\temppsdreports2011\" & strfilename)

    '--> Working with individual workbooks
    Set psdsht = indv.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With psdsht
        LRow = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    '--> Set Month from Workbook Title
    mnth = Split(strfilename, " ")(3)

    For i = 2 To 13
        With eoyrsht
            .Cells(i, 1) = mnth
        End With
    Next

    '--> Copy No. Items
    '--> Copy Gross Value
    '--> Copy Final Error Value
    '--> Tidy Up
    indv.Close

    strfilename = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

**Edit:**

I understand why they are all being populated with December since the For Loop is running 12  times in total with the main loop. I may be approaching a solution myself but welcome any comments.

Comment: I am prepping an answer, but I have question first. Will the month names always be in the same order for each workbook? So Jan, Feb, Mar, or the order depend on what mnth is?

Comment: Each workbook in the folder is for a particular month. Within each is data I will later copy to this main spreadsheet (EOYR - End of Year Report). Does that help?

Comment: Just as an FYI the Dir() function is so super clunky. There is a FileSystemObject object which is so much better for navigation/file operations like this. You need to add a reference to the MicroSfot Scripting Runtime to use it.

Comment: +1 Will look into FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes sense:

```
For i = 2 To 13
    With eoyrsht
        .Cells(i, 1) = mnth
    End With
Next
```

populates the first column from line 2 to 13 with the same `mnth`, which is the month of the spreadsheet that you have opened in your Do Until loop. So the last loop, which presumably opens the December spreadsheet will override whatever you have done previously.

You probably meant something like:

```
i = 2
Do Until ...
    ....
    With eoyrsht
        .Cells(i, 1) = mnth 'puts the month of the spreadsheet you are looking at in line i
    End With
    i = i + 1 'increments i for the next spreadsheet's month
    ....
Loop
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I realised why it was happening but didn't know how to solve it while you answered. Thanks. Will accept when I can.